# Prove that $f: (0,1)\to \mathbf{R}$ is surjective.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, inverse, inverse-function

I wanted to find an algebraic bijection from $(0,1)$ to $\mathbf{R}$ (not the overused $\tan^{-1}$ variation.) I came up with [$f$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zg6xopr7ps)$: (0,1)\to \mathbf{R}$ $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{1-x}$$ and proved injectivity quite trivially. But I came to a screeching halt when trying to prove that it was indeed onto. I supposed $f(x_c)=c$ for some $c\in \mathbf{R}$ and tried to unravel $f$ for $x_c$ in terms of $c$. I came to $$x_c=\frac{c+2-\sqrt{c^2+4}}{2c}$$ but I have to show that $x_c\in (0,1).$ [This](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ohp3xelan8) graph settled my nerves as it shows what I want to prove (indeed, it is the graph of $f^{-1}$), but how would one argue this algebraically?

Comment: For surjectivity, why not use some version of the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: @OsamaGhani I suppose because I am trying to assign this as an extra credit question for an Honors *algebra* exam and I am trying to avoid proofs using continuity and such.

Comment: Have you considered rationalising the numerator? You'll get:$$x_c = \frac{2}{c + 2 + \sqrt{c^2 + 4}}.$$As it stands, your inverse is not defined at $c = 0$, whereas the rationalisation is. It would then just fall to showing $c + 2 + \sqrt{c^2 + 4} > 2$, which is easy enough.

Comment: @TheoBendit I was just coming to say that I did exactly this. Don't know why it took me so long. Thank you.

Comment: @chrischristopherson Noticed your graph in Desmos; graphing the original limited to $(0,1)$ makes it clear visually that it’s invective and surjective. Not a proof but was thinking there was an argument that 1-1 and unbounded on $(0,1)$ implied it was onto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leaving the $c=0$ case aside, which $f^{-1}(0)$ should be $\frac 12$.

Rationalise the numerator in different ways for $x_c$, $x_c-1$ and $x_c-\frac12$:

$$\begin{align*}
x_c &= \frac{c+2-\sqrt{c^2+4}}{2c} \tag{0}\\
&= \frac{(c+2)^2-(c^2+4)}{2c\left(c+2+\sqrt{c^2+4}\right)}\\
&= \frac{4c}{2c\left(c+2+\sqrt{c^2+4}\right)}\\
&= \frac{2}{c+2+\sqrt{c^2+4}} \tag{1}\\
\end{align*}$$

Line $(1)$ shows that: if $c>0$ then $x_c > 0$.

(Slightly less obviously, this holds also for $c<0$. For all $c\ne 0$, $\sqrt{c^2+4}+c > 0$, so $x_c>0$.)

---

$$\begin{align*}
x_c &= \frac{c+2-\sqrt{c^2+4}}{2c}\\
&= 1+\frac{-c+2-\sqrt{c^2+4}}{2c}\\
&= 1+\frac{-4c}{2c\left(-c+2+\sqrt{c^2+4}\right)}\\
&= 1-\frac{2}{-c+2+\sqrt{c^2+4}} \tag{2}\\
\end{align*}$$

Line $(2)$ shows that: if $c<0$ (i.e. $-c > 0$), then $x_c < 1$.

(Slightly less obviously, this holds also for $c>0$. For all $c\ne 0$, $\sqrt{c^2+4}-c > 0$, so $x_c<1$.)

---

$$\begin{align*}
x_c &= \frac{c+2-\sqrt{c^2+4}}{2c}\\
&= \frac12 + \frac{2-\sqrt{c^2+4}}{2c}\\
&= \frac12 + \frac{-c^2}{2c\left(2+\sqrt{c^2+4}\right)}\\
&= \frac12 - \frac{c}{2\left(2+\sqrt{c^2+4}\right)} \tag{3}
\end{align*}$$

Line $(3)$ shows that:

- if $c>0$, then $x_c < \frac12 < 1$;
- if $c<0$, then $x_c > \frac12 > 0$.

---

To conclude, for all real $c\ne 0$,

$$0 < \frac{c+2-\sqrt{c^2+4}}{2c} < 1$$

Answer (score 0):

Being a rational function with the denominator having no zeros in the open interval $(0,1)$ this function is differentiable there and  its derivative  is negative showing it is monotonically decreasing. And hence it is 1-1.

Let us evaluate it rational numbers of the form 1/n which turns out to be
$$f\bigg(\frac1n\bigg) = n-1-\frac1{n-1}.$$ This shows that the function takes arbitrarily high values.

Evaluating at  the rational number $(n-1)/n$ we see that
the value is $\frac{n}{(n-1)}-n$ which shows it takes values highly negative without bounds. Combined with intermediate value theorem this shows the range is the whole real line.